# How to estimate multilevel Poisson models in lme4 with large count values?

Tags: r, lme4, poisson

**The case:**
I am trying to estimate gravity models of migration (`mig`) from 55 origin districts (`IDo`) to 54 destination districts (`IDd`). Two important predictors are the distance (`dist`) between each origin and destination district and an indicator variable of the contiguity (`contig`) of any origin-destination pair. The migration outcome variable is a measure of the count of people migrating between pairs of districts (ranging from zero to a couple of thousands). Below is a test data set that approximates my data situation. In the real data, the migration outcome variable is slightly less ideally poisson distributed (`min=0, max=9450, mean=85, median=10`).

```
library(lme4)

#*** Generate test data set
set.seed=777
td=data.frame(IDo=rep(1:55,each=55),IDd=rep(1:55,times=55),dist=runif(3025,0.186,12.7),contig=rbinom(3025,1,p=0.08), stringsAsFactors=F)
td=td[td$IDo!=td$IDd,]              # remove cases for which origin and destination are the same
td=rbind(td,td)                     # dublicate data for two years
td$year=rep(c(1,0),each=2970)       # generate year dummy variable
td$mig=rpois(5940, lambda = 1)*1000 # generate migrant count variable

# Cross-classified random effects Poisson models
m1=formula(mig~dist+contig+year+(1|IDo)+(1|IDd))
fm0=glmer(m1,data=td,family="poisson",control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"), nAGQ=0) # Adaptive Gauss-Hermite Quadrature
fm1=glmer(m1,data=td,family="poisson",control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"), nAGQ=1) # Laplace Approximation

# Regular Poisson models
m2=formula(mig~dist+contig+year+factor(IDo)+factor(IDd))
fm2=glm(m2,data=td,family="poisson")
```

**The problem:**
I am running cross-classified multilevel Poisson models using `lme4`. When using the default nAGQ=1 setting (`fm1`), I always get the following warning message, and in the real data case, the model fails to converge (`In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, control$checkConv Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00248588 (tol = 0.001, component 1)`).

```
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?
```

However, this problem does not emerge with setting of nAGQ=0 (`fm0`) or when running it as a regular fixed effects model (`fm2`).

*Does anyone have a suggestion what to do to avoid the problem that underlies this warning message (and leads to convergence issues in the real data)?* The predictor variables have all a reasonably small scale, so no need to rescale these variables. I could potentially rescale my outcome variable to have smaller values (`td$mig=round(td$mig/1000,0)`) but this would change the distribution and should not be done as indicated in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270/poisson-regression-with-large-data-is-it-wrong-to-change-the-unit-of-measuremen).

Comment: See  [this cross-validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110004/how-scared-should-we-be-about-convergence-warnings-in-lme4) discussion of convergence failures. If you haven't already.

Comment: I just had a look at the discussion of convergence failure. But I am not entirely sure if my problem is related to a solver issue or more a general issue of not being able to use Poisson models when the count values get too high. On the other hand, Poisson models are particularly designed for these type of count data and I really don't understand why the "model is nearly unidentifiable".

Comment: did my answer resolve your problem/answer your question?

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, thanks for your help! Although it doesn't resolve the problem that I have in my real data, using a different optimizer gets rid of the warnings in the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think this is a false positive; it's unusual to have count data with such large counts ... have you tried fitting with different optimizers (see `?lme4::convergence`) ?  (I just tried your example with `control=glmerControl(optim="nloptwrap")` and got near-identical results.)

I'm a little worried about your distributional assumptions.  I know it's just a reproducible example, but drawing a Poisson sample and multiplying it by 1000 does **not** give you a Poisson-distributed value ... here's a little posterior predictive simulation that simulates the distribution of the 90th quantile of the response under the fitted model -- which is *way* different from the observed value ...

```
ss <- simulate(fm1,1000,seed=101)
qq <- sapply(ss,quantile,0.9)
hist(qq,breaks=50,col="gray")
summary(qq)
##   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##   1106    1153    1167    1168    1182    1255 
quantile(td$mig,0.9) ## 2000
```

Comment: You are definitively correct about the distribution of my artificial Poisson variable with large values. The problem is that I don’t really know how to otherwise generate a Poisson distributed variable with count values in the range of 0 to 9000. However, I don’t think that this case is “unusual”. At larger aggregation units (e.g., counties, states, districts, nations, etc.) you will often end up with large counts of certain phenomena (e.g., number of accidents per county, the number of malaria infections in a district, the number of children underweight in a country, etc.).

Comment: Here are the results using the lme4::convergence tests on my real data:
1. I rescaled the independent variables (using scale) but still get the convergence failure and large eigenvalue warning.
2. There was no detectable singularity issue any(diag.vals < 1e-6)=FALSE
3. The gradient and Hessian with the Richardson extrapolation produce similar values.
4. Restarting the fit from the original values still produces the warnings.
5. The results of the allFit function indicate that all optimizers worked (ss$which.OK==TRUE) although I get the wranings.

Comment: So I have to conclude that the lme4 Poisson routine is quite sensitive to large count values.